# How to Link Another Static Library to my Static Library in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm **making a static library for iOS which uses React Native** internally. I expect React Native to be present in the project which uses my library.

I tried setting my Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths to `$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)` and `$(SRCROOT)/node_modules/react-native/React` (`React` directory has the .h files I'm looking for).

Till now, nothing has worked. I still get a `XXX.h not found` error while building.

What is the solution/best practice for doing this?

**UPDATE**

I fixed this. I added `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React` to my User Header Search Paths and everything built correctly. But again, **is this the right way to do it?**

Comment: I'm on Xcode 6.2 building for iOS 8.2.

Comment: Just wondering, have you tried this in a project in which react is not present? ie react-native static library inside a true native app?